Allow submitting a review after flagging a post
I flagged this question as AI generated.

Yet I can not mark the post as flagged. None of the possible options seems appropriate and I can not submit the review.
In my opinion, that should be an option when reviewing and flagging a post, maybe even an option in the sidebar to make it more prominent.

You always have the option to use the Skip button (though this has the possibility of it being automatically published).

In this particular case with AIGC...

non-serious/joke suggestion: publish, and downvote.

more serious suggestion: point the user to https://stackoverflow.com/help/gen-ai-policy, tell them to rewrite in their own words, and vote "requires major changes".



Honestly, once you've generated a question with GenAI, the cat is pretty much out of the bag. Rewording GenAI content still makes it GenAI content, just better disguised. It is unlikely the user will start from scratch and write up a question as they would have without the use of GenAI. This holds more true for answers, but imo it applies to all posts equally.

@ErikA I'm assuming good intent here- the case where it's a genuine question and not some kind of weird scheme to build reputation.

Imo intent does not matter when using GenAI, we have a ban of all use. I assume everyone using it thinks they are contributing positively. I don't see how obfuscating that GenAI was used achieves anything. The recent high-profile case pretty much did this, using GenAI, then sometimes rewriting, testing and adapting to provide good answers.

While that could be a workaround for some posts, some posts just need flagging and then be dealt with in the flag queue (Spam, non-questions, astroturfing etc). So I'm not going to accept this answer, as I still think flagging should be an option to end the review of an item.

The question is not asking whether to flag the post or not. It's asking what to do,  after flagging the post, in order to complete the Staging Ground review. Your answer, joke aside, seems somewhat reasonable. However, it's unclear whether you're actually proposing to allow AI-generated content in Staging Ground. As a clarification, flagging the post as suspected AI content is obviously correct, and a moderator is expected to follow up as with any other flag for AI-generated content.
